# Multiple functions on one list?

Tags: list, haskell

i have a list

```
[1,1,1,1,1]
```

and i am trying to write function which will return list

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

i want to use function map like this

```
map (+1) [1,1,1,1,1]
```

which will return

```
[2,2,2,2,2]
```

after that i want to call map function on last four elements of returned list so after i get [2,2,2,2,2] i want to use map on last four [2,2,2,2] that will return [3,3,3,3] and replace last four elements from first map call so i get [2,3,3,3,3] etc..

```
map (+1)[1,1,1,1,1] 
map (+1)  [2,2,2,2] 
map (+1)    [3,3,3] 
map (+1)      [4,4] 
map (+1)        [5]
```

returned:

```
[2,2,2,2,2]
[2,3,3,3,3] 
[2,3,4,4,4]
[2,3,4,5,5]
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

i need to return only last list...
btw this is only Simplified version, originaly i have list of lists ... i just cant figure how to call function how i described..
thanks.

Comment: Should all immediate steps be returned? Or only the last list, [2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: And how can we help you?

Comment: only last list [2,3,4,5,6]

Answer (score 8):

I think you want something like

```
mapTails f [] = []
mapTails f (x:xs) = f x : mapTails f (map f xs)
```

Answer (score 4):

IMO the most elegant way would be

```
zipWith($) $ iterate((+1).) id
```

Comment: Fantastic! I think it should be `zipWith($) $ tail $ iterate((+1).) id`.

Comment: I like this solution most.  The others are either not generic enough or not very elegant. +1.  Although I would use more haskelly syntax and no `($)`:  `zipWith ($) (iterate (succ .) succ) (replicate 5 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

`scanl` *almost* does what you want:

```
Prelude> scanl (+) 1 [1,1,1,1,1]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

You could drop the first item, which is just the initial state value we're passing in:

```
Prelude> tail $ scanl (+) 1 [1,1,1,1,1]
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: I don't think OP is seeking this function, though it yields the right answer for the case `(+1)`. For other input function, e.g. `(+2)`, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you're looking for using a recursive function, instead:

```
myFn :: Num a => [a] -> [a]
myFn []     = []
myFn (x:xs) = x + 1 : (myFn $ map (+1) xs)

main = print $ myFn [1,1,1,1,1]  -- Prints [2,3,4,5,6]
```

See http://codepad.org/wBwynlGt

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do what you want?

```
startList = [1,1,1,1] -- orwhatever you want it to be 
map (\(x,i) -> x + i) $ zip startList [1..]
```

The `zip` basically pairs each element in the list with what you want to add to it, and the map function then adds each element in the list to that value to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm version O(n<sup>2</sup>) time:

```
plusSlow :: [Int] -> [Int]
plusSlow [] = []
plusSlow (x:xs) = (head mapped):(plusSlow $ tail mapped)
                 where mapped = map (+1) (x:xs)
```

Faster version O(n) time:

```
plusFast :: [Int] -> [Int]
plusFast x = pf x 1

pf :: [Int] -> Int -> [Int]
pf [] _ = []
pf (x:xs) n = (x+n):(pf xs (n+1))
```